# ant design bundled twice in single bundle after upgrade

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, antd

I recently updated antd to recent one `3.9.1` , where they have done some changes in `Icons` components, now after building bundle and seeing bundle analyzer i saw there is 2 ant-design module bundled, one is `@ant-design` and another is `antd`, even in `antd` bundle there `Icon` is bundled.
I have also added recommended plugin `babel-plugin-import` as per their docs.
[image]